# Add to cart issue in some android devices

Tags: addtocart

I am facing issue in my website while clicking "ADD TO CART", it is redirecting to home page without adding the product to cart.This issue is occurring only in android 6, android 7 devices and is working fine in other devices.

Comment: check by changing theme in backend, try with default magneto themes like default or rwd..... or disable if you installed any 3rd party plugins by app/etc/modules folder, also check var/log error once.....